# Webscrapping using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

Let's consider the page following:

https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/8618/Stages/19793/Fixtures/England-Premier-League-2021-2022

I want to extract to `R` all the matches that were played. To do so I wrote a code:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
url <- read_html("https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/8618/Stages/19793/Fixtures/England-Premier-League-2021-2022")
names <- url %>% html_nodes(".divtable-row") %>% html_text()
names
```

where `".divtable-row"` was extracted with selector gadget. The problem is that output of this code is equal to `character(0)`. It somehow does not see the area that I'm marking. Do you know why it happens?

[image]

Comment: Note that `rvest` can only see the raw HTML source for a web page. If you right click on the page and choose "view source" you can see what `rvest` sees. Note that R vest cannot execute javascript code. Most "modern" webpage uses javascript to build HTML content after the page loads. The data you are trying to scrape is simply not in the HTML page at the time the page loads. You'll either need to write a special parser to grab the data out of the javascript code or use something like RSelenium that can execute javascript.

Comment: RSelenium likely better option given nature of required session cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider something like :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
url <- "https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/8618/Stages/19793/Fixtures/England-Premier-League-2021-2022"
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

web_Obj_Table <- remDr$findElement("id", "tournament-fixture")
text_Table <- web_Obj_Table$getElementText()[[1]]
stringr::str_extract_all(text_Table, "\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}FT\\n[:alpha:]*(|[:space:]*[:alpha:]*)\\n\\d{1,2}[:space:]:[:space:]\\d{1,2}\\n[:alpha:]*(|[:space:]*[:alpha:]*)\\nMatch Report")

[[1]]
 [1] "14:00FT\nEverton\n1 : 0\nChelsea\nMatch Report"                  "14:00FT\nTottenham\n3 : 1\nLeicester\nMatch Report"             
 [3] "16:30FT\nWest Ham\n1 : 2\nArsenal\nMatch Report"                 "20:00FT\nManchester United\n3 : 0\nBrentford\nMatch Report"     
 [5] "15:00FT\nChelsea\n2 : 2\nWolverhampton\nMatch Report"            "15:00FT\nBurnley\n1 : 3\nAston Villa\nMatch Report"             
 [7] "15:00FT\nBrentford\n3 : 0\nSouthampton\nMatch Report"            "17:30FT\nBrighton\n4 : 0\nManchester United\nMatch Report"      
 [9] "19:45FT\nLiverpool\n1 : 1\nTottenham\nMatch Report"              "14:00FT\nLeicester\n1 : 2\nEverton\nMatch Report"               
[11] "14:00FT\nNorwich\n0 : 4\nWest Ham\nMatch Report"                 "16:30FT\nManchester City\n5 : 0\nNewcastle\nMatch Report"       
[13] "20:00FT\nAston Villa\n1 : 2\nLiverpool\nMatch Report"            "19:45FT\nLeicester\n3 : 0\nNorwich\nMatch Report"               
[15] "19:45FT\nWatford\n0 : 0\nEverton\nMatch Report"                  "20:15FT\nWolverhampton\n1 : 5\nManchester City\nMatch Report"   
[17] "12:00FT\nTottenham\n1 : 0\nBurnley\nMatch Report"                "14:00FT\nLeeds\n1 : 1\nBrighton\nMatch Report"                  
[19] "14:00FT\nWolverhampton\n1 : 1\nNorwich\nMatch Report"            "14:00FT\nWest Ham\n2 : 2\nManchester City\nMatch Report"        
[21] "14:00FT\nWatford\n1 : 5\nLeicester\nMatch Report"                "14:00FT\nAston Villa\n1 : 1\nCrystal Palace\nMatch Report"      
[23] "20:00FT\nNewcastle\n2 : 0\nArsenal\nMatch Report"                "19:45FT\nSouthampton\n1 : 2\nLiverpool\nMatch Report"           
[25] "19:45FT\nEverton\n3 : 2\nCrystal Palace\nMatch Report"           "20:00FT\nChelsea\n1 : 1\nLeicester\nMatch Report"               
[27] "16:00FT\nArsenal\n5 : 1\nEverton\nMatch Report"                  "16:00FT\nBrighton\n3 : 1\nWest Ham\nMatch Report"               
[29] "16:00FT\nBurnley\n1 : 2\nNewcastle\nMatch Report"                "16:00FT\nChelsea\n2 : 1\nWatford\nMatch Report"                 
[31] "16:00FT\nCrystal Palace\n1 : 0\nManchester United\nMatch Report" "16:00FT\nLeicester\n4 : 1\nSouthampton\nMatch Report"           
[33] "16:00FT\nLiverpool\n3 : 1\nWolverhampton\nMatch Report"          "16:00FT\nManchester City\n3 : 2\nAston Villa\nMatch Report"     
[35] "16:00FT\nNorwich\n0 : 5\nTottenham\nMatch Report"
```